# grub-efi-amd64-signed error prevents installing any software

Tags: 17.04

I have installed ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop and everything went well during 5 months but since few days I start encounter this error

When trying to execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ppa-purge is already the newest version (0.2.8+bzr63).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 128
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the exact command(s) you run, and their full output ?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 reached the end of its support life cycle (and thus became off topic here) in mid January, while Ubuntu 17.10 was released in October. You should upgrade to a supported release or reinstall one from scratch. You’re welcome to [open a new question](/questions/ask) if you have trouble with that.